# Jquery Ajax post request returns success, but Rails/Sqlite database not getting updated

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, sqlite

I'm trying to create a new review using an Ajax post request to send data to a rails create function, but it doesnt seem to be working. The AJAX request returns success, but when I check the database there isnt a new review.

My ajax request is here:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/reviews/new",
      data: { review: { email: review_email, rating: review_rating, comment: review_comment} },
      success: function(data){
        console.log("SUCC");
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(data){
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
```

and my Rails review controller looks like this:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def index
    @reviews = Review.all
    @review = Review.new
  end
  def new
    @reviews = Review.new
  end

  def create
    @email = params[:email]
    @rating = params[:rating]
    @comment = params[:comment]
    @review = Review.create(review_params)

    if @review.save
      redirect_to @review    
    else
    end
  end

  def show
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
   @review = Review.destroy(params[:id])
 end

  private
    def review_params
      params.permit(:email, :rating, :comment)
    end
end
```

I'm new to Rails so a lot of the rails stuff might be disgusting as I've used like 10 different tutorials to try and solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be a little confused about which routes do what. If you do a `bin/rails routes` (or `bin/rake routes` depending on your Rails version), you should see something like this for reviews:

```
      reviews GET    /reviews(.:format)          reviews#index
              POST   /reviews(.:format)          reviews#create
   new_review GET    /reviews/new(.:format)      reviews#new
  edit_review GET    /reviews/:id/edit(.:format) reviews#edit
       review GET    /reviews/:id(.:format)      reviews#show
              PATCH  /reviews/:id(.:format)      reviews#update
              PUT    /reviews/:id(.:format)      reviews#update
              DELETE /reviews/:id(.:format)      reviews#destroy
```

These are normal REST/Rails routes so:

1. `GET /reviews` is for listing a bunch of reviews.
2. `POST /reviews` is for creating a new review, hence the `#create` controller method associated with this route.
3. `GET /reviews/new` is for getting a "create a new review" page.
4. `GET /reviews/:id/edit` is for getting an "edit the `:id` review" page.
5. `GET /reviews/:id` is for getting the details for review `:id`.
6. `PATCH /reviews/:id` and `PUT /reviews/:id` are for updating review `:id` with some new information.
7. `DELETE /reviews/:id` is for deleting review `:id`.

Your `$.ajax` call is POSTing to **3** (which would normally use GET) when it should be POSTing to **2** so you were just using the wrong route. You want `url: '/reviews'` in your `$.ajax` call since `POST /reviews` is what you use to create a new resource.

Comment: You should actually be getting a "404 - Not Found" error if the routes are correctly declared since `/new` in rails only responds to GET.

Comment: The key thing to remember here is that the GET `/new` and `/:id/edit` routes are solely to display a form to the user. Its the non-idempotent POST and PUT/PATCH routes that actually do something.

Comment: @max Hard to know what's going on (or what routes are set up) to allow `POST /reviews/new` to "work". Thanks for fixing that typo.

Comment: @muistooshort Yeah one of the tutorials I was following had me set up a post route for reviews/new, didnt notice it until a little bit later... Definitely getting the hang of it now, I appreciate the help guys!